# What happen in Thread program if start() method calls within it's own body?

Tags: java, multithreading

Please give me some vivid explanation in this regards.
 I have tried lots but i couldn't figured it out.

I'm completely messed up with the code segment of start method calling like recurrence in below program and even how start method called first time before entered into start method body.

Thanks in advance.

```
package appletexample;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class AppletOne extends Applet implements Runnable {

    String str = "This is a simple Banner ";
    Thread t ;
    boolean b;

    public void init() {
          setBackground(Color.gray);
          setForeground(Color.yellow);
    }

    public void start() {
          t = new Thread(this);
          b = false;
          t.start();
    }

    public void run () {
          char ch;
          for( ; ; ) {
              try {
                  repaint();
                  Thread.sleep(200);
                  ch = str.charAt(0);
                  str = str.substring(1, str.length());
                  str = str + ch;
              } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
          }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
          g.drawRect(1,1,300,150);
          g.setColor(Color.yellow);
          g.fillRect(1,1,300,150);
          g.setColor(Color.red);
          g.drawString(str, 1, 150);
    }
}
```

Im even newbie to Thread concept please give me clear picture related on it. and give me some reference website to understand thread concept with applet and web based programming.

Comment: And what's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `start()` on a thread that's already been started — you'll get an `IllegalThreadStateException`.  However, your program isn't doing that.

In your applet's `start` method, you create a `Thread` and pass the applet itself as the `Runnable` argument.  This means that when the thread is started, it'll call the applet's `run` method.  Then you call `start()` on the thread to start it running.  But you're calling `start()` on the thread, not the applet, so you're not accidentally running the applet's own `start` method again.  There's no recursion happening here.

---

However, you're starting a thread and never stopping it.  That's bad.  Your applet needs to clean up after itself and not leave the thread running forever even after the applet itself has been destroyed.  The way to do that is:

First, make your `run` method actually respond to thread interruption.  In your `catch (InterruptedException e)` block, put a `return` statement instead of just ignoring the exception.  (See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/) for more information on thread interruption.)

Second, add a `stop()` method to your applet — like `start()`, this is defined in the `Applet` class, and it'll be called automatically when it's time for your applet to stop.

Third, in your new `stop()` method, do `t.interrupt()` followed by `t.join()`.  This will tell the thread that it should stop running, then wait for it to do so.

Comment: is is typical/ok to paint the applet from a background thread?

Comment: he should use the init method of the applet though, doesn't he?

Comment: @Kevin, the thread calls `repaint()`, but that doesn't actually perform painting immediately; it just asks the UI thread to call `paint` soon.  I believe it's OK to call `repaint()` in a non-UI thread.

Comment: @UniversE, the use of `start()` looks reasonable to me, but not having a corresponding `stop()` is a problem since the thread keeps running.  I've updated my answer to address that.

Comment: @Wyzard: So my point of reference is the windows world, where painting from a non-UI thread doesn't work (all UI update happens from one thread, and background threads that want to update the UI post messages back to the UI thread). Just wondering if that's true for applets too (I haven't looked at applet code since 1999 or so).

Comment: @Kevin, that's true in Java AWT (including applets) too, but the `repaint()` method doesn't actually perform repainting.  It just sends a message to the UI thread *requesting* repainting.  The UI thread calls `paint`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code segment is not entirely the best practice and `start()` method should almost never be overridden.

```
public void start()
   {
      t = new Thread(this);
      b = false;
      t.start();
   }
```

Rename your `start()` method and call it from within the caller method.

Comment: Don't you confuse the thread start() method with the Applet start() method?

Comment: It's not _wrong,_ but it does create the illusion that the author does not fully understand how to create and use threads.

Comment: true .. i came out with the wording a little too strong. Because people would rarely need to override `start()`